# form_valid updateview

Tags: django-models, django-views

Good day dear Community!

my Model:

```py
class CheckList(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ...
    datecompleted = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

form.py:

```py
class CompletionChecklistForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CheckList
        fields = ('vessels_name', 'datecompleted')
```

now I'd like to update 'datecompleted' field:

views.py:

```py
class CompleteItemView(UpdateView):
    model = CheckList
    form_class = CompletionChecklistForm
    template_name = 'completion_checklist.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.datecompleted = timezone.now()
        form.instance.save()
        return super(CompleteItemView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Template:

```py
{% block content %}

<h2 class="d-flex justify-content-center">Completion of current Checklist</h2>
<br>
<br>
<container class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="form-group w-50">
        <h4>Complete: {{ object.vessels_name }}?</h4><br>
        {{ object.datecompleted }}
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="clearfix">
                <button class="btn btn-danger float-left" type="submit">Yes</button>
                <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-secondary float-right">No, back</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</container>

{% endblock %}
```

There is no error message but and field value doesn't change as well.
Am I right with my View?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `form_valid` will never call this with a `pk` specified, `so pk=None`, furthermore you override the `form` variable with `CheckList` object. In your HTML you furthermore have no *submit* button, so you never make a POST request to the view.

Comment: Hi Willem! Added change, but same result..

Comment: It is `form.instance.datecompleted = timezone.now()`, likely the form is also invalid since you do not send a value for the `vessel_name` or for the `datecompleted` to the form, so likely it will run `form_invalid()` since the form does not contain the necessary data in the POST request.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it's time to revert back to my lessons..)